# Tools for generating Haskell function dependency (control flow) graph?

Tags: haskell, code-analysis, static-analysis

Note not "functional dependency". Are there tools available that allow me to build a static function dependency graph from source code? Something which indicates to me which functions depend on which other ones in a graphical manner.

Comment: You mean a "call graph"?

Comment: What about a tool that allows one to generate a `cabal` file with `Build-depends`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Yes, there certainly are. If you look in the [Development](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:development) category on Hackage, you'll find tools for:

- graphing [package dependencies](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pkggraph) -- n.b requres older cabal
- graphing [module dependencies](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/graphmod)
- graphing [function calls](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SourceGraph)
- graphing [running data structures](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vacuum)

In particular, [SourceGraph](http://code.haskell.org/~ivanm/Sample_SourceGraph/Graphalyze/Graphalyze.html#analysis-of-the-entire-codebase) contains many analysis passes, including:

- visualizing [function calls](http://code.haskell.org/~ivanm/Sample_SourceGraph/Graphalyze/Graphalyze.html#visualisation-of-overall-function-calls)
- computing cyclomatic complexity
- visualizing [module imports](http://code.haskell.org/~ivanm/Sample_SourceGraph/Graphalyze/Graphalyze.html#visualisation-of-imports)

Other tools that you might be interested in are:

- HPC, for [visualizing test coverage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hpc)
- ThreadScope, for [visualizing runtime behavior](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/threadscope)
- lscabal, [extract modules from a package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lscabal)

Here is the functional call graph produced by SourceGraph run over cabal2arch:

[image]

Comment: +1: Argh, I was about to post the same thing. I suspect SourceGraph is closest what qrest is after.

Comment: failed to install  SourceGraph ..  seems like this project is not maintenanced ?

Comment: luochen1990, I have the same problem. The problem seems to be that my compiler's authors moved onto a new version of the "binary" package without ensuring that all other packages using it were ready to move on and without alternatively improving cabal to support the situation. I suspect that with the older version of the compiler SourceGraph will still work with all its bytes intact and fully maintained.

Comment: The link to SourceGraph does not work anymore but here is the hackage package: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/SourceGraph.

Comment: SourceGraph seems to be dead. Any alternatives?