# Tracing the evaluation of an expression in functional programming

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, erlang, code-analysis, static-analysis

This question talks about Erlang, but it applies to other functional programming language as well.

#### The Question

Say in the middle of a function definition, there is an expression like this:

```
A = B + voodoo(C, D)
```

and `voodoo` is defined as

```
voodoo(X, Y) -> more_voodoo(more_voodoo1(X), more_voodoo2(Y)).
```

and `more_voodoo*` is defined like `voodoo`, the list goes on, after some steps, it ultimately reached literals, BIFs, library functions (later these are called "border").

The question is: I want to know how `A` is defined, how can I generate a graph to illustrate the definition of `A`? like this:

```
C -> more_voodoo1 ---+
                     |-> more_voodoo ---+
D -> more_voodoo2 ---+                  |-> (+) -> A
  (graph inferred from context) -> B ---+
```

How the graph is organized is not really important here, as long as it let me clearly see the definition of `A` (with high enough abstraction and zoom in when necessary).

Intuitively, you can think the program is some threads going through some balls, where the treads represent the data flow and the balls represent functions, and what I want to do is pick the ball that produces `A`, and **shake** it, as a result, only what related to `A` is left, all other non-interesting information gets shaked off.

I doubt that there exists off-the-shelf tool for this, so what's your opinion on how to implement a tool for this kind of task? it won't have to be fully automatic, it can try its best and when it gets stuck it can ask the user for instructions (just black box it, user defined borders, etc.), parse the source code? hooks into the compiler? use some kind of "radio active" values and then x-ray it?

#### Note

You may wonder, why don't just flow the code and understand it? Well, sometimes the call chain is too long, and it's really hard to keep all the stack at your head, sure, if we try hard enough, we will understand it eventually, but if there is a better way to do it, why not? and to be honest, sometimes these codes are biz logic, not really something interesting to dive into, and this is a once for all solution, once we have the tool, we won't be scratch our head next time. With a graph, you can see clearly where certain data comes from (and it interacts with user better that text, yeah, I know you love pure text, I love it too, but admit it, there are times when GUIs are more convenient than text).

If your call chain is that long, you probably should refactor it, I heard you say. Well, sucks or not, sometimes you are not allowed to change those code.

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431225/tools-for-generating-haskell-function-dependency-control-flow-graph) is close to what you need.

Comment: yeah... it does